# Вид сказуемого при наличии местоимения "весь"

Tags: грамматика

Чем выражено сказуемое и какова роль местоимений "всё, весь" в следующих предложениях:

(1)  Небо всё в тучах.

(2) Всё небо в тучах.

(3) Автобус приехал весь в грязи.

Спасибо за внимание и за ваши ответы.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(1) Небо всё в тучах. Основа - *небо в тучах*. Всё - определение с дополнительным обстоятельственным значением меры, степени; ср.небо в тучах *(в какой мере?) всё,  полностью, без остатка*.

(2) Всё небо в тучах. Основа - *небо в тучах*. Всё - в препозиции определение к слову небо; небо *какое? всё*.

(3) Автобус приехал (?) весь в грязи. Основа - *автобус приехал в грязи*. Весь - определение с дополнительным обстоятельственным значением меры, степени; ср. автобус (приехал) в грязи (*в какой мере, степени?) весь.*

Comment: Екатерина, большое спасибо за ответ. Значит, получается, что при изменении позиции местоимение переходит их состава подлежащего в состав сказуемого? Но при этом грамматической  связью оно связано с подлежащим? Похоже на дуплексив, но тогда надо считать, что в сочетании "всё в тучах" главным словом является "всё". Как в думаете?

Comment: Хороший вопрос Вы задали. Думаю, что "всё в тучах" - это определённая синтаксическая конструкция, но не словосочетание.   Сравним: Небо (было) всё в тучах. Оба компонента сочетания "всё в тучах"зависят и от слова "небо", и от предполагаемой связки "было", но каждый компонент отдельно. А друг от друга они не зависят.

Comment: А может быть, от изменения позиции местоимения ничего не меняется, и оно в обоих случаях относится к подлежащему, являясь определением, и в состав сказуемого не входит?

Comment: Да, скорей всего.